# Can not change brightness on Toshiba P855 - tried every distro already

Tags: desktop, laptop, brightness

I'm trying to use Linux on a Toshiba P855 laptop. And I have one big problem: the screen brightness can't be changed, and stays at maximum.

Tried different distros, also tried many boot options in the `/etc/default/grub` file, but no success. Currently I'm with Kubuntu 12.04, and the function keys for brightness don't work (they never did on any distro), so I'm able to use only the slider for the brightness. But even then - nothing really changes.

All is working on Windows. What's wrong here?

EDIT: Additional information

Well, in `/sys/class/backlight` I have a symlink:

`toshiba -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM: 00/TOS1900:00/backlight/toshiba/`

and in that `toshiba` folder I have:

- actual_brightness
- bl_power
- brightness

device -> `../../../TOS1900:00/`

- max_brightness
- power (folder)
- subsystem -> ...
- type
- uevent

and in `/proc/acpi/` I have:

- ac_adapter (folder)
- battery (folder)
- button (folder)
- event
- toshiba (folder)
- wakeup

Comment: Do you have some brightness-control-files in `/sys/class/backlight/` or in `/proc/acpi/`?

Comment: Probably, you want this for eye problems? I managed to change the brightness on my Debian, but I have forgotten how (but it was the hardware keys) - anyway, I stopped all that and now exclusive use a projector (no TV, no devices) and my desktop looks like [this](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/pics/emacs_dump.png) - that's Emacs, but the shell looks the same (I use the Linux VTs/ttys/"console") - i.e., fullscreen (no swapping back and forth between windows, BLACK background, and LARGE font). Your problems may be less severe, but if they get worse, remember those things - they work.

Comment: Looks like there's simply no kernel / driver support for the specific model / chipset the P855 has.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [xbacklight](http://xorg.freedesktop.org/releases/individual/app/).  It uses the XRandR interface to set the backlight (Works on my ThinkPad running FC17)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command in your terminal

```
sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=XX
```

replacing XX with a hex number 00 is darkest (this will black out your screen so don't advise going for that) and FF is the brightest.

If this works I would suggest putting it in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Last month the NVidia video driver updated itself, and now I'm able to change the brightness ;) :) ... it's version 319.32 now.
(Changing is not from the Fn keys - they still don't work - but from the slider in the "Battery monitor" popup ... but it's OK for me ;) ...)